# Jetpack Compose: LazyRow onScrollListener

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I was wondering if there is a way or a resource I could refer to in order to achieve a side effect on a `LazyRow` when an item is scrolled?
The side effect is basically to call a function in the viewModel to alter the state of the list's state.

- The side effect should be only executed only if the current firstVisibleItemIndex after
- scroll is different than before
  The side effect should not be executed the item is not fully scrolled
  I am implementing a fullscreen `LazyRow` items with a snap behavior

So far I have tried `NestedScrollConnection`

```kotlin
class OnMoodItemScrolled : NestedScrollConnection {
    override suspend fun onPostFling(consumed: Velocity, available: Velocity): Velocity {
        viewModel.fetchItems()
        return super.onPostFling(consumed, available)
    }
}
```

The issue with the above is that the side effect is going to be executed anyway even-though the item displayed after the scroll is the same as before the scroll.

I also tried to collecting the listState interaction as the following

```kotlin
val firstVisibleItem: Int = remember { sectionItemListState.firstVisibleItemIndex }
    sectionItemListState.interactionSource.collectIsDraggedAsState().let {
        if (firstVisibleItem != sectionItemListState.firstVisibleItemIndex) {
            viewModel.fetchItems()
        }
    }
```

The issue with the above is that the side effect is going to be executed the second the composable is composed for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue using a `LaunchedEffect` with 2 keys.

```kotlin
val sectionItemListState = rememberLazyListState()
val flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(sectionItemListState)
var previousVisibleItemIndex by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf(0)
}
val currentVisibleItemIndex: Int by remember {
    derivedStateOf { sectionItemListState.firstVisibleItemIndex }
}
val currentVisibleItemScrollOffset: Int by remember {
    derivedStateOf { sectionItemListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset }
}

LaunchedEffect(currentVisibleItemIndex, currentVisibleItemScrollOffset) {
    if (previousVisibleItemIndex != currentVisibleItemIndex && currentVisibleItemScrollOffset == 0) {
        // The currentVisible item is different than the previous one && it's fully visible
        viewModel.fetchItems()
        previousVisibleItemIndex = currentVisibleItemIndex
    }
}
```

Using both `currentVisibleItemIndex` and `currentVisibleItemScrollOffset` as keys will make sure that the `LaunchedEffect` will be triggered whenever one of them changes. Moreover, checking if the `previousVisibleItemIndex` is different than the `currentVisibleItemIndex` will ensure that we only trigger this effect only if the visible item is changing.
However, this condition will true **also** if the use has partially scrolled and since I have a snapping effect it will go back to the previous position. Which will result in triggering the effect **twice**.
In order to make sure that we only trigger the effect only in case were we **actually** scrolled to the next/previous fully visible position we need to rely on the `scrollOffset`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`LazyListState#firstVisibleItemIndex`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState#firstVisibleItemIndex()) to get the information about the first visible item and store this value.   When the value changes the item is scrolled up.

Something like:

```
@Composable
private fun LazyListState.itemIndexScrolledUp(): Int {
    var previousIndex by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemIndex) }
    return remember(this) {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (firstVisibleItemIndex > previousIndex) {
                //scrolling up
                previousIndex
            } else {
                - 1
            }.also {
                //Update the previous index
                previousIndex = firstVisibleItemIndex
            }
        }
    }.value
}
```

and then:

```
val state = rememberLazyListState()
var index = state.itemIndexScrolledUp()

DisposableEffect(index){

     if (index != -1) {
          //...item is scrolled up
     }

      onDispose {  }   
}


LazyColumn(
        state = state,
){
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @gabriele-mariotti this is very close to what i needed!
The only issue with it is that it will trigger whenever the user is scrolling even though the currentVisibileItem snapped back to the previous one (partial scroll). I will post the final answer

Comment: @AouledIssa In this case you can check if the item is fully visible using `layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo`.

Comment: in case of a partial scroll (when both items are visible) the `layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo` list will contain both of them. I was looking forward to get only the fully visible item.

Comment: @AouledIssa yes, but you can check `firstItem.offset < layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset` to know if it is partially visible.

Comment: @AouledIssa in any case, your answer works fine.

Comment: In my case it crashes the app when i try this `if (sectionItemListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo[currentVisibleItemIndex].offset < sectionItemListState.layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset) { ... }`

Comment: You have also to check `if (layoutInfo.totalItemsCount == 0) { .... }`